# Refresh all images on page

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following script to update images on a page displaying webcams. The webcam images are pulled by FTP. Because I want to implement a filtering interface, using mixitup, I don't want the whole page to refresh as this will clear any filters.

So the above script does work... kind of. The problem here is that eventually the image URL will become too long and won't display.

Does any one have a suggestion on how this can be resolved?

Cheers!

```js
function imgRefresh() {
  var now = new Date();
  for (i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
    document.images[i].src = document.images[i].src + "?" + now.getTime();
  }
  setTimeout('imgRefresh()', 5 * 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `replace` with regex:-

```js
function imgRefresh() {
  var now = new Date();
  for (i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
    var src = document.images[i].src.replace(/\?\d+/, '');
    document.images[i].src = src + '?' + now.getTime();
  }
  setTimeout(imgRefresh, 5000);
}
```

`/\?\d+/` looks for **?** followed by **numbers**, which it will then replace with the new time.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for looking at this ! The suggestion you've made seems to stop the refresh from working all together. Any thoughts? Thanks. Brad

Answer (score 0):

You can use split(), "`?`" as a delimiter and grab the first part of the result, which would be the original url.

Example:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function imgRefresh() {
    var now = new Date();
    for(i=0; i<document.images.length; i++) {
        document.images[i].src= document.images[i].src.split("?")[0];
        document.images[i].src = document.images[i].src + "?"+now.getTime();
    }
    setTimeout('imgRefresh()', 5*1000);
}

</script>
```

Documentation on [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for looking at this! The script you've suggested seems to cause a small flicker where it shows the first posted image. Cheers. Brad